# Kurento, WebRTC and p2p browser to browser media streaming

Tags: browser, streaming, media, p2p

I wanted to know, if there's a way that, I can configure Kurento as media recording server, not media stream relay.

I want to keep the p2p essence of WebRTC between the browsers, and just use Kurento as signaling server as well as optional media recording server.